# Create clickable item on listview

Tags: android, android-listview

How to make a clickable item in a listview and get the data directly from the DB when clicking it? Should I use a cursor and get the column names in the cursor??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, create a SimpleCursorAdapter and interface it with your database with a given layout. Once you have this then you can immediately pull from the callback on the listview and then cast it to the same type (cursor) then then pull information relative to that specific row and you should be golden!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make use of simpleadapter and cursor. Pick the position clicked on the list and retrieve data from the same position in cursor.